# Filtering out punctuation marks

Tags: swift, filter, punctuation

```
struct Mirror {
    var size: Int
    var name: String
}
let mirrors = [(name: "Dorian", size: 24), (name: "Corinth", size: 33), (name: "Cruyf", size: 29), (name: "Lola", size: 46)]
let smallMirrors = mirrors.filter {$0.size < 33 }
print(smallMirrors)
```

The problem here is that the result in Playgrounds is ["Dorian", 24 "Cruyf, 29"] - all marks included.

I want a list
Dorian 24
Cruyf 29
no "" or commas

Comment: What exactly is it that you want? `print(smallMirrors)` to output `Dorian 24 Cruyf 29` ?

Comment: i think that's kind of what the OP wants

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate with tuples through the `smallMirrors`:

```
for (k,v) in smallMirrors{
    print(k, terminator: " ")
    print(v)
}
```

Or an even better solution, using maps:

```
smallMirrors.map { (k,v) in
    print(k, v)
}
```

**Output:**

```
Dorian 24
Cruyf 29
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want no quotation marks and everything on the same line, you can use

```
import UIKit

struct Mirror {
    var size: Int
    var name: String
}
let mirrors = [(name: "Dorian", size: 24), (name: "Corinth", size: 33), (name: "Cruyf", size: 29), (name: "Lola", size: 46)]
let smallMirrors = mirrors.filter {$0.size < 33 }
smallMirrors.forEach{ print("\($0) \($1)", terminator:" " )}
```

Output:

```
Dorian 24 Cruyf 29
```

By modifying the "terminator" property of print, you can divide entries however you want. If you decide you do want each entry on a new line, just remove the terminator entirely. By taking this functional approach to the print statement, you have the flexibility to add any separators, punctuation, or other strings you may want in the future without issue.